# Generate random numbers summing to a predefined value

Tags: python, random

So here is the deal: I want to (for example) generate 4 pseudo-random numbers, that when added together would equal 40. How could this be dome in python? I could generate a random number 1-40, then generate another number between 1 and the remainder,etc, but then the first number would have a greater chance of "grabbing" more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
b = random.randint(2, 38)
a = random.randint(1, b - 1)
c = random.randint(b + 1, 39)
return [a, b - a, c - b, 40 - c]
```

(I assume you wanted integers since you said "1-40", but this could be easily generalized for floats.)

Here's how it works:

- cut the total range in two randomly, that's b. The odd range is because there are going to be at least 2 below the midpoint and at least 2 above. (This comes from your 1 minimum on each value).
- cut each of those ranges in two randomly. Again, the bounds are to account for the 1 minimum.
- return the size of each slice. They'll add up to 40.

Comment: I think you need `a = random.randint(1, b-1)` and `c = random.randint(b+1, 39)` to make sure that you don't get zeros in the output list.  Also, this has a slightly peculiar distribution:  results of the form `[1, 1, x, 38-x]` are significantly more likely to occur than they would be for a uniform distribution.

Comment: @Mark: I believe you are correct. I had a couple of off by one errors in there.

Answer (score 122):

Here's the standard solution.  It's similar to Laurence Gonsalves' answer, but has two advantages over that answer.

1. It's uniform: each combination of 4 positive integers adding up to 40 is equally likely to come up with this scheme.

and

2. it's easy to adapt to other totals (7 numbers adding up to 100, etc.)

```
import random

def constrained_sum_sample_pos(n, total):
    """Return a randomly chosen list of n positive integers summing to total.
    Each such list is equally likely to occur."""

    dividers = sorted(random.sample(range(1, total), n - 1))
    return [a - b for a, b in zip(dividers + [total], [0] + dividers)]
```

Sample outputs:

```
>>> constrained_sum_sample_pos(4, 40)
[4, 4, 25, 7]
>>> constrained_sum_sample_pos(4, 40)
[9, 6, 5, 20]
>>> constrained_sum_sample_pos(4, 40)
[11, 2, 15, 12]
>>> constrained_sum_sample_pos(4, 40)
[24, 8, 3, 5]
```

Explanation:  there's a one-to-one correspondence between (1) 4-tuples `(a, b, c, d)` of positive integers such that `a + b + c + d == 40`, and (2) triples of integers `(e, f, g)` with `0 < e < f < g < 40`, and it's easy to produce the latter using `random.sample`.  The correspondence is given by `(e, f, g) = (a, a + b, a + b + c)` in one direction, and `(a, b, c, d) = (e, f - e, g - f, 40 - g)` in the reverse direction.

If you want *nonnegative* integers (i.e., allowing `0`) instead of positive ones, then there's an easy transformation:  if `(a, b, c, d)` are nonnegative integers summing to `40` then `(a+1, b+1, c+1, d+1)` are positive integers summing to `44`, and vice versa.  Using this idea, we have:

```
def constrained_sum_sample_nonneg(n, total):
    """Return a randomly chosen list of n nonnegative integers summing to total.
    Each such list is equally likely to occur."""

    return [x - 1 for x in constrained_sum_sample_pos(n, total + n)]
```

Graphical illustration of `constrained_sum_sample_pos(4, 10)`, thanks to @FM.  (Edited slightly.)

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  # The universe.
|                    |  # Place fixed dividers at 0, 10.
|   |     |       |  |  # Add 4 - 1 randomly chosen dividers in [1, 9]
  a    b      c    d    # Compute the 4 differences: 2 3 4 1
```

Comment: +1 This was informative -- thanks. I edited your answer, adding a graphical illustration that helped me figure out the algorithm. Normally, I would be reluctant to do that, but I thought others might find it useful. Feel free to alter or undo my edit.

Comment: Captain, I am detecting large amounts of win in this sector! +1

Comment: @FM:  Thanks;  nice addition.  I did edit it slightly to suit my 0-based view of the universe;  I hope this doesn't affect the clarity.

Comment: If you need to constraint the generated integers to be higher than a certain value ``low``, this can be done by replacing ``a - b`` with ``a - b + (low-1)`` and to compensate for the ``n*(low-1)`` increase in the new sum by replacing the two instances of ``total`` with ``total - (min-1)*n``. I haven't figured out a way to add a ``high`` threshold too.

Comment: Any luck on a `high` threshold?

Comment: This answer is so good and well-written. I don't understand why this is not the accepted answer. I think many people are looking for this answer.

Comment: To allow zeros in the set you could use `random.choices()` instead of `sample()`

Comment: @JonasLindeløv, thanks for this addition! 
Just a note. 
In the term `total - (min-1)*n`, I am sure you meant `total - (low-1)*n`.

Answer (score 21):

Use [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) distribution

```
from numpy.random import multinomial
multinomial(40, [1/4.] * 4)
```

Each variable will be distributed as a binomial distribution with mean `n * p` equal to `40 * 1/4 = 10` in this example.

Comment: Clearly the cleanest and sturdiest solution, but probably a bit more explanation in the answer would have helped the OP understand _why_ this is the best answer

Comment: This seems to produce values close to equal, rather than arbitrary ones in the desired range: `multinomial(2**16, [1/3] * 3)/2**16` -> `array([0.33073425, 0.33273315, 0.33653259])` (multiple runs give similar results). Doesn't look uniform to me

Comment: That wasn't my complaint. The sum is indeed correct. The issue is with the uniformity of the samples. They will hover closely to just evenly split intervals, rather than sometimes giving a few much larger or smaller ones. The top-voted answer does manage that.

Comment: @kram1032, they are not uniform, they are binomial, with mean `n * p` which is `1/3 * 2**16 ~ 21k` in your case. OP didn't ask for uniformity.

Comment: Ah fair enough, indeed, uniformity wasn't asked for.

Answer (score 8):

Generate 4 random numbers, compute their sum, divide each one by the sum and multiply by 40.

If you want Integers, then this will require a little non-randomness.

Comment: This will create a non-uniform distribution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068956/2075003

Answer (score 3):

There are only 37^4 = 1,874,161 arrangements of four integers in the range [1,37] (with repeats allowed).  Enumerate them, saving and counting the permutations that add up to 40.
(This will be a much smaller number, N).

Draw uniformly distributed random integers K in the interval [0, N-1] and return the K-th permutation.  This can easily be seen to guarantee a uniform distribution over the space of possible outcomes, with each sequence position identically distributed.  (Many of the answers I'm seeing will have the final choice biased lower than the first three!)

Comment: This answer does not generalize very well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a humble improvement to [@Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson)'s version to allow zeros in the generated integers (so that they are non-negative, rather than positive):

```py
import random

def constrained_sum_sample_pos(n, total):
    """Return a randomly chosen list of n non-negative integers summing to total.
    Each such list is equally likely to occur."""

    dividers = sorted(random.choices(range(0, total), k=n-1))
    return [a - b for a, b in zip(dividers + [total], [0] + dividers)]
```

The function [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) samples *with* replacement, as opposed to `random.sample()` which samples without replacement. It's new from Python 3.6.

Comment: Interesting! The OP didn't specify what distribution they wanted, but it's worth noting that in this solution the distribution can be a bit odd, especially for small `n`. For example, with `n = 3` and `total = 2`, there are six solutions: (`[0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]`). It looks as though this code would give `[0, 1, 1]` approximately half the time and `[0, 0, 2]` and `[1, 0, 1]` one quarter of the time (each).

Answer (score 0):

If you want true randomness then use:

```
import numpy as np
def randofsum_unbalanced(s, n):
    # Where s = sum (e.g. 40 in your case) and n is the output array length (e.g. 4 in your case)
    r = np.random.rand(n)
    a = np.array(np.round((r/np.sum(r))*s,0),dtype=int)
    while np.sum(a) > s:
        a[np.random.choice(n)] -= 1
    while np.sum(a) < s:
        a[np.random.choice(n)] += 1
    return a
```

If you want a greater level of uniformity then take advantage of the multinomial distribution:

```
def randofsum_balanced(s, n):
    return np.random.multinomial(s,np.ones(n)/n,size=1)[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Building on [@markdickonson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3590105/75033) by providing some control over distribution between the divisors.  I introduce a variance/jiggle as a percentage of the uniform distance between each.

```
 def constrained_sum_sample(n, total, variance=50):
    """Return a random-ish list of n positive integers summing to total.

    variance: int; percentage of the gap between the uniform spacing to vary the result.
    """
    divisor = total/n
    jiggle = divisor * variance / 100 / 2
    dividers = [int((x+1)*divisor + random.random()*jiggle) for x in range(n-1)]
    result = [a - b for a, b in zip(dividers + [total], [0] + dividers)]
    return result
```

Sample output:

```
[12, 8, 10, 10]
[10, 11, 10, 9]
[11, 9, 11, 9]
[11, 9, 12, 8]
```

The idea remains to divide the population equally, then randomly move them left or right within the given range.  Since each value is still bound to the uniform point we don't have to worry about it drifting.

Good enough for my purposes, but not perfect. eg: the first number will always vary higher, and the last will always vary lower.