# Dividing a number into m parts uniformly randomly

Tags: java, random

How do I divide a large positive integer ***n*** into ***m*** parts *uniformly randomly*. 
Post-condition: Adding up all the **m** parts should give **n**.

Below is my attempt(in java like pseudocode), but I don't think it will give me uniformly random distribution. 
I am first finding the average part *avg* by dividing n/m. Then I am generating *m-1* random numbers which are around avg in magnitude(by alternately generating random numbers between *0 & avg*, and *avg & 2*avg*. Then I am subtracting the sum of these *m-1* numbers from original number *n* and setting that as the *m*'th part.

Assume that the function *rand(x, y)* returns a random number uniformly between x and y.

```
int[] divideUniformlyRandomly(int n, int m)
{
    int[] res = new int[m];
    int avg = n / m;
    int sum = 0;
    bool alternator = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
    {
        if(alternator == false)
        {
            res[i] = rand(0, avg);
            alternator = true;
        }
        else
        {
            res[i] = rand(avg, 2*avg);
            alternator = false;
        }
        sum += res[i];
    }
    res[m-1] = n - sum;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the actual code to be in java? Please put a language tag, otherwise nobody will see your question later, since `random` is not a very popular tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting N random numbers that the sum is M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m).  Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622608/choosing-n-numbers-with-fixed-sum

Comment: Also check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab) which has a very good answer.

Comment: Whoa! I need to work on my searching skills. I tried finding possible duplicates but couldn't.

Comment: @Prab I searched for [random] "sum"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public double[] divideUniformlyRandomly(double number, int part) {
    double uniformRandoms[] = new double[part];
    Random random = new Random();

    double mean = number / part;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i<part / 2; i++) {
        uniformRandoms[i] = random.nextDouble() * mean;

        uniformRandoms[part - i - 1] = mean + random.nextDouble() * mean;

        sum += uniformRandoms[i] + uniformRandoms[part - i -1];
    }
    uniformRandoms[(int)Math.ceil(part/2)] = uniformRandoms[(int)Math.ceil(part/2)] + number - sum;

    return uniformRandoms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should divide n in m parts using m - 1 uniformy distributed fences. Your code could be :

```
int[] divideUniformlyRandomly(int n, int m)
{
    int[] fences = new int[m-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < m - 2; i++)
    {
        fences[i] = rand(0, n-1);
    }
    Arrays.sort(fences);

    int[] result = new int[m];
    result[0] = fences[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < m - 2; i++)
    {
        result[i] = fences[i+1] - fences[i];
    }
    result[m-1] = n - 1 - fences[m-2];

    return result;
}
```

To illustrate this :
[image]

Comment: have you plotted the values you get for this?  are they uniformly distributed?

Comment: @andrewcooke I just saw that my answer is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8064754/436792. The most upvoted answer to the same question actually says that this method produces a uniform distribution.

Comment: ok, i was asking whether the individual values are uniform.  which is not the same as asking whether the points are uniformly distributed on an n-1 dimensional plane.  i still don't understand fully, but my original plot is irrelevant.