# choosing random numbers N time in a day with sum M

Tags: php, random, bots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing n numbers with fixed sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622608/choosing-n-numbers-with-fixed-sum)

I'm developing a Bot for my Bux system in PHP. the Bot should run `N` times in a day and each time create variable (random) `K` users in a manner that sum of users in the day be fixed (`M`).
How can I achieve this? (Choosing Random number `N` times that sum of numbers be `M`).

Comment: i don't think its duplication ??? What do you think @Snigger

Comment: @Truth: I only need first number and my choosing is discrete. My `M` changes each time I need a new number (Previous`M` - Previous`K`)

Comment: This PHP code would help you ..... http://codepad.viper-7.com/knf4h9 ... wrote it for you but your question was already closed

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? You want to generate N random number which has a pre-known, fixed value. This is exactly what's being asked on the linked question.

Comment: @Snigger I also wrote up a solution. You can view it online at http://codepad.org/fcaZgyXm with accompanying blog at http://sampsonblog.com/246/n-parts-for-sum-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function generate_random_sum($sum = 100)
{
    $out = array();
    while(array_sum($out) !== $sum)
    {
        $out[] = mt_rand(1, ($sum - array_sum($out)));
    }
    return $out;
}

print_r(generate_random_sum(100));
```

Does this help?

It will give you an array of different values totalling M in your question. Not sure how to make it create N amount of users if anyone wants to extend feel free.