# Haskell Random cannot construct the infinite type: a1 = IO a1

Tags: haskell, random, io

I want to generate a list with 26 random integers which sum is 301 with Haskell. I write the following:

```
import System.Random

f 1 sum = [sum]
f n sum = m : (f (n-1) (sum-m))
    where m = randomRIO (0,sum)
```

but it can't be compiled! I am confused with IO!

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 = IO a1
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `m'
In the expression: m : (f (n - 1) (sum - m))
In an equation for `f':
    f n sum
      = m : (f (n - 1) (sum - m))
      where
          m = randomRIO (0, sum)
```

Comment: You have already got the answers regarding haskell, but I think that the algorithm is not ideal for generate random numbers.  For example 'f 20 100' returns [85,14,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. Tou will get long zero tail as the result of this algorithm.  As first approach I will try to choose another strategy - divide your sum in random proportins.  For example f 5 100 - divide the 100 in random proportion (for example 30 and 70) and call f for each of this numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is somewhat confusing in this case, but the punchline is that you need to work in the `IO` monad, since it's using `randomRIO` which is in `IO`, and there is (by design) no way to run `IO` code from non-`IO` code.

```
f 1 sum = return [sum]
f n sum = do
  x  <- randomRIO (0, sum)
  xs <- f (n - 1) (sum - x)
  return (x : xs)
```

Comment: It's OK. Some results:*Main> f 26 301
[215,33,6,12,7,1,4,4,15,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
*Main> f 26 301
[284,1,1,13,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
*Main> f 26 301
[297,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 5):

As an aside to what hammer wrote, the error message becomes a lot more clear if you write the type you expect for the `f` function:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
f 1 sum = [sum]
f n sum = m : (f (n-1) (sum-m))
    where m = randomRIO (0,sum)
```

gives the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `IO Int'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `m'
    In the expression: m : (f (n - 1) (sum - m))
    In an equation for `f':
        f n sum
          = m : (f (n - 1) (sum - m))
          where
              m = randomRIO (0, sum)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Which pretty much tells you exactly what is wrong - that is `m` has type `IO Int` rather than `Int`

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, your algorithm will not give uniformly-distributed output.

An easy way to get uniform output is:

- Generate `n-1` random numbers in the range from `0` to `sum` (inclusive)
- Insert `0` and `sum` into the list of random numbers
- Sort the resulting list
- Return the list of differences between consecutive values in the sorted list

Example:

- Suppose we want four integers with a sum of 100, we request three random values from the RNG and it gives us `[72,33,43]`
- We insert `0` and `100` and sort the list, giving `[0,33,43,72,100]`
- We compute the differences `[33-0, 43-33, 72-43, 100-72]`
- The result would be `[33,10,29,28]`

In Haskell:

```
randomsWithSum :: (Num n, Ord n, Random n) => Int -> n -> IO [n]
randomsWithSum len sum =
    do b <- sequence $ take (len-1) $ repeat $ randomRIO (0,sum)
       let sb = sort (sum:b) in
           return $ zipWith (-) sb (0:sb)
```

For your example you would call this as `randomsWithSum 26 (301::Int)`

The same applies to floating-point types, e.g. `randomsWithSum 4 (1::Double)`

---

**Edit** Swapped the arguments, so that `` 26 `randomsWithSum` 301 `` does what its name suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment by demas, I tried to tweak your algorithm. We probably want each of the `n` numbers be "the same" as all the others, so we'll just try until we get the correct sum. Maybe there is a better way.

```
-- f 0 rng = return []
-- f n rng = randomRIO (0,rng) >>= (\x-> fmap (x:) $ f (n-1) rng)

g n sumval = 
  let s = 2*sumval `div` n  -- expected value upto z is probably z/2,
      h i = do              --              if all are equally likely
              xs <- sequence $ replicate n (randomRIO (0,s))
              if sum xs == sumval 
                then return (xs, i)       -- i is number of attempts
                else h (i+1)
  in h 1

-- test:
Prelude System.Random> g 26 301
([15,23,15,0,13,8,23,11,13,19,5,2,10,19,4,8,3,9,19,16,8,16,18,4,20,0],2)
Prelude System.Random> g 26 301
([20,14,3,6,15,21,7,9,2,23,22,13,2,0,22,9,4,1,15,10,20,7,18,1,18,19],12)
Prelude System.Random> g 26 301
([4,3,4,14,10,16,20,11,19,15,23,18,10,18,12,7,3,8,4,9,11,5,17,4,20,16],44)
Prelude System.Random> g 26 301
([6,6,22,1,5,14,15,21,12,2,4,20,4,9,9,9,23,10,17,19,22,0,10,14,6,21],34)
Prelude System.Random> g 26 301
([20,9,3,1,17,22,10,14,16,16,18,13,15,7,6,3,2,23,13,13,17,18,2,2,8,13],169)
```

Comment: This has a different problem, though: It's impossible for any element to be more than ```2*sumval `div` n```.

Comment: @hammar that's by design. I think the expected value for each will be thus `sumval/n`, and there are `n` of them.

Comment: @hammar IOW that's not a problem, that's a proposed solution.

Comment: Yes, but it's not enough to just have the correct expectation. If every list with sum `sumval` should be equally probable, then the probability of the list `[sumval, 0, 0, 0, ...]` should be non-zero, but with this code it's zero for lists with 3 or more elements.

Comment: @hammar If to follow your interpretation, that the solution is simple: just call `permutations` after the original code. Whether each such list will be equally probable, is a separate question. Perhaps the problem is underspecified wrt to the range of elements.

Comment: @hammar here's what I tried to overcome: with lists where each elt's range is `[0..sumval]`, the randomness is exhausted halfway through the list - if we just keep the running sum, and when sumval is reached, all the rest **will have to be 0**. If we want all the numbers in the list equally random, perhaps we have to limit the range of each, as I did. But I don't know much (if at all) about probabilities.

Comment: Yes, I see what you were trying to do, but to get a uniform distribution is harder than that. And just shuffling the list after the original code won't do either, it'll still be biased towards lists with mostly zeroes.

Comment: @hammar right, so my algo won't have that problem. And since the Q is under-specified wrt to individual ranges, I think this is a valid answer.

Comment: There is a better way, but this isn't it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622608/choosing-n-numbers-with-fixed-sum