# Python random size and element

Tags: python, arrays, random

I have to create an array in Python with random elements, random numbers of      elements. The only important thing is that: the sum of all elements  should be equal to 1024

Examples: range of elements `min=1`, `max=1024`, `sum=1024`.

1. case: `[1000, 13, 11]`, 3 elements, their sum is `1024`.
2. case: `[500, 200, 100, 2, 22, 150, 50]`, 7 elements, their sum is `1024`.

It doesn't matter if there are identical number `[512, 512]`. Can someone explain me how to do that?

Comment: Your cases don't satisfy: `Size = # of elements`

Comment: All numbers would have to be one in order to satisfy such a condition and the minimum of 1.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3590105/646543 (look at the top-voted answer, not the accepted answer)

Comment: Michael0x2a thank u to u too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is:

#### input:

```
import random
b =[]
a = 0
c = 0
d = 1024
while True:
    a = random.randint(1,d)
    c = c + a
    if c<1024:
        b.append(a)
    else:
        a = 1024 - c +a
        b.append(a)
        break
print b
```

#### output:

```
b = [29, 473, 292, 230] = 1024
```

(lower "d" equals to a longer "b" list)

Comment: @NicolaCurrò is the size of `b` (4) equal to sum of elements (1024)?

Comment: @marmeladze yes it is: 29+473+292+230 = 1024

Comment: "the size should be equal to the sum of all elements".

as i understand for  `A = (a_1, a_2, a_3 ... a_n)`. size (`len(A)`) is `n`. sum of elements (`sum(A)`) is `a_1+a_2+a_3+...a_n`. are they equal?

i'm just curious of, if @NicolaCurrò had expressed himself clearly.

Comment: @marmeladze yes, size= a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+....a_n