# How to randomly divide an integer into a fixed number of integers, such that the obtained tuples are uniformly distributed?

Tags: r, random, integer-division

Based on this reply: [Random numbers that add to 100: Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab/8068956#8068956)
I tried to apply the suggested method to randomly divide an integer into a fixed number of integers whose sum is equal to the integer. Although that method seems to result in a uniformly distributed set of points when the values are *not* integers, in the case of integers, the resulting tuples are not obtained with equal probability.
This is shown by the following implementation in R, where a simple case is tested with 3 divisors and with the integer to be divided equal to 5:

```
# Randomly divide an integer into a defined number of integers 
# Goal: obtain with equal probability any combination of variable values, with the condition that sum(variables) = dividend.

# install.packages(rgl)  # Install rgl package if not yet installed. This allows to use the plot3d function to create a 3D scatterplot.
library(rgl)

n_draws = 10000
n_variables = 3  # Number of divisors. These need to be randomly calculated. Their value must be in the interval [0:dividend] and their sum must be equal to the dividend. Two variables can have the same value.
dividend = 5  # Number that needs to be divided.
rand_variables = matrix(nrow = n_draws, ncol = n_variables)  # This matrix contains the final values for each variable (one column per variable).
rand_samples = matrix(nrow = n_draws, ncol = n_variables-1)  # This matrix contains the intermediate values that are used to randomly divide the dividend.

for (k in 1:n_draws){
    rand_samples[k,] = sample(x = c(0:dividend), size = n_variables-1, replace = TRUE)  # Randomly select (n_variables - 1) values within the range 0:dividend. The values in rand_samples are uniformly distributed.
    midpoints = sort(rand_samples[k,])
    rand_variables[k,] = sample(diff(c(0, midpoints, dividend)), n_variables)  # Calculate the values of each variable such that their sum is equal to the dividend.
}

plot3d(rand_variables)  # Create a 3D scatterplot showing the values of rand_variables. This plot does not show how frequently each combination of values of the n_variables is obtained, only which combinations of values are possible.

table(data.frame(rand_variables))  # This prints out the count of each combination of values of n_variables. It shows that the combinations of values in the corners (e.g. (5,0,0)) are obtained less frequently than other combinations (e.g. (1,2,2)).
```

The last line gives the following output, which shows how many times were obtained each combination of values of (X1, X2, X3) that respect the condition X1 + X2 + X3 = 5:

```
, , X3 = 0

   X2
X1    0   1   2   3   4   5
  0   0   0   0   0   0 397
  1   0   0   0   0 471   0
  2   0   0   0 469   0   0
  3   0   0 446   0   0   0
  4   0 456   0   0   0   0
  5 358   0   0   0   0   0

, , X3 = 1

   X2
X1    0   1   2   3   4   5
  0   0   0   0   0 450   0
  1   0   0   0 539   0   0
  2   0   0 560   0   0   0
  3   0 588   0   0   0   0
  4 426   0   0   0   0   0
  5   0   0   0   0   0   0

, , X3 = 2

   X2
X1    0   1   2   3   4   5
  0   0   0   0 428   0   0
  1   0   0 603   0   0   0
  2   0 549   0   0   0   0
  3 461   0   0   0   0   0
  4   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5   0   0   0   0   0   0

, , X3 = 3

   X2
X1    0   1   2   3   4   5
  0   0   0 500   0   0   0
  1   0 549   0   0   0   0
  2 455   0   0   0   0   0
  3   0   0   0   0   0   0
  4   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5   0   0   0   0   0   0

, , X3 = 4

   X2
X1    0   1   2   3   4   5
  0   0 465   0   0   0   0
  1 458   0   0   0   0   0
  2   0   0   0   0   0   0
  3   0   0   0   0   0   0
  4   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5   0   0   0   0   0   0

, , X3 = 5

   X2
X1    0   1   2   3   4   5
  0 372   0   0   0   0   0
  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
  2   0   0   0   0   0   0
  3   0   0   0   0   0   0
  4   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As the output shows, the combinations of values in the corners of the plane (e.g. (5,0,0)) are obtained less frequently than other tuples.

How can I obtain any integer tuple with the same probability?

I'm looking for a solution that is applicable for any positive integer and for any number of divisors.

Comment: Does the order make a difference in your tuples?
i.e. do you want the probability of (5,0,0) to be the same as the probability of (0,2,3), or do you want the probability of:
(5,0,0) OR (0,5,0) OR (0,0,5) to be the same as the probability of:
(0,2,3) OR (0,3,2) OR (2,0,3) OR (2,3,0) OR (3,0,2) OR (3,2,0)

Comment: Yes the order makes a difference. Thanks for the question.

In the example shown above, there are a total of 21 distinct possible tuples that meet the conditions. Each should have the same probability of being generated (i.e. a probability of 1/21).

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3589214/270986), which is essentially the same problem (but for Python).

Comment: Thanks for the link Mark. However, TheTime's solution is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think trying to make these combinations/permutations manually is reinventing the wheel.  There are efficient algorithms to do this implemented in `partitions`.  For example,

```
library(partitions)                            # compositions, parts, restrictedparts may be of interest
sample_size <- 1000
pool <- compositions(5, 3)                     # pool of possible tuples
samp <- sample(ncol(pool), sample_size, TRUE)  # sample uniformly

## These are you sampled tuples, each column
z <- matrix(pool[,samp], 3)
```

Side note: don't use a data.frame, use a matrix to store a set of integers.  data.frames will be entirely copied every time you modify something (`[.data.frame` is not a primitive), whereas matrices will modify in place.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!