# Genrating random (int) list of given sum python

Tags: python, random

I want to simulate **n** random choices with given probabilities **prob**.

My current solution is the following:

```
from random import choices

result = [0]*len(prob)
population = list(range(0,len(prob)))
ch = choices(population, weights=prob, k=n)
for i in ch:
   result[i] += 1
```

My problem is that I call this code a large number of times and usually with large **n** and this solution does not seem efficient at all.

Is there a better way of doing it (like a pre-build function of some library)?

To sumarize I want the most efficient way of building a random list summing to $n$ such that the probability of obtaining a given list is equal to the probability of obtaining this list as **n** random choices with probability **prob**.

Thank you

**[EDIT to add context]**

What I am really doing is **n** random walks in a kind of Markov chain as follow:

```
def rand_walk(n,state):
    next_states,prob = complicated_function(state) // compute the next states and their probability
    succ = distribute_over_next_states(n, prob) // compute how many walk goes to which states
    accu = complicated_function_2(state) // accumulator for the result
    for ns in range(0,len(next_states)):
        accu += rand_walk(succ[i],next_states[I])
    return accu
```

The point is that the computation of the next states and their probability is costly thus I avoid computing it to many times (thus I avoid doing **n** runs sequential). That is why I want to distribute the **n** following the given probability.

I hope this is somehow clear enough to understand ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a list of random numbers, summing to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1)

Comment: my guess would be using numpy. There should be some efficient random implementations.

Comment: @Mathieu I would like to have integers. I don't think the pointed question request integers. Does it?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html is the only one i know

Comment: @wece hmm i am sry then. I will search for an answer. Actually you already got one using numpy :D.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174422/discussion-between-tombombadil-and-wece).

Comment: How random are the numbers supposed to be? E.g., with your appraoch, for large `n` each count should end up pretty much exactly at the probability for that position, whereas "true" random numbers should allow wider variation, as long as the sum remains the same.

Comment: @tobias_k They must be as random as n random choices with the given probabilities ... For n large enough it will indeed be close to the probability times n but that's not random enough for me.

Comment: @wece I am not sure I understand what you mean with that. Do you mean that each list that sums to N should be equally likely?

Comment: @wece True, I was a bit fast. Here is the right one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589214/generate-multiple-random-numbers-to-equal-a-value-in-python

Comment: @Mathieu Those are uniform random numbers. The values we are generating are  distributed normally about `n/len(prob)`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I edited to explain what I wanted to do.

Comment: @tobias_k I hope it is clearer with the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmph. Numpy's already implemented [multinomial draws](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html), so we don't even need the `via_binomial` function:

```
In [56]: np.random.multinomial(10**8, [0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
Out[56]: array([20003098, 29996630, 50000272])

In [57]: via_binomial(10**8, [0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
Out[57]: [19993527, 30000996, 50005477]
```

---

IIUC, you can treat this as a series of repeated binomial draws:

```
from random import choices
import numpy as np

def original(n, prob):
    result = [0]*len(prob)
    population = list(range(0,len(prob)))
    ch = choices(population, weights=prob, k=n)
    for i in ch:
       result[i] += 1
    return result

def via_binomial(n, prob):
    result = []
    already_handled_prob = 0
    n_left = n
    for p in prob[:-1]:
        draw_prob = p / (1 - already_handled_prob)
        result.append(np.random.binomial(n_left, draw_prob))
        already_handled_prob += p
        n_left -= result[-1]
    result.append(n-sum(result))
    return result
```

gives me

```
In [29]: %time original(10**6, [1])
Wall time: 343 ms
Out[29]: [1000000]

In [30]: %time via_binomial(10**6, [1])
Wall time: 0 ns
Out[30]: [1000000]

In [31]: %time original(10**6, [0.25, 0.75])
Wall time: 343 ms
Out[31]: [249944, 750056]

In [32]: %time via_binomial(10**6, [0.25, 0.75])
Wall time: 0 ns
Out[32]: [250030, 749970]

In [33]: %time original(10**8, [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])
Wall time: 40.1 s
Out[33]: [40004163, 29999878, 19992540, 10003419]

In [34]: %time via_binomial(10**8, [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])
Wall time: 0 ns
Out[34]: [39997530, 29999334, 20003182, 9999954]

In [35]: %time via_binomial(10**8, [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])
Wall time: 0 ns
Out[35]: [40009324, 29995955, 19996223, 9998498]
```

(Okay, I'm kind of cheating using `%time` and not `%timeit` there. :-)  On my machine it's about ~3-10 us.)

Comment: Wow this is great ! exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @wece: hold up, it looks like numpy's already implemented the multinomial distribution, so you might not need this at all..

Comment: Ha ! yes they did: np.random.multinomial is the function I'm looking for. Thank you for pointing that to me :)

Answer (score 1):

use `numpy` and `collections.Counter`? `Counter` is a mapping (dict-subclass) that makes more sense for the results you are trying to describe than a list.

```
import random
import collections
import numpy as np

def f(population, prob, n):
    return collections.Counter(np.random.choice(population, p=prob/np.sum(prob), size=n))

x = list(range(5))

f(x, x, 10000) # --> Counter({1: 986, 2: 1993, 3: 3009, 4: 4012})
```

Timings

```
%timeit f(x, x, 10000)
1.87 ms ± 18.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# for comparison
def g(population, prob, n):
    return collections.Counter(random.choices(population, weights=prob, k=n))

%timeit g(x, x, 10000)
4.97 ms ± 56.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit your_function_in_op(x, x, 10000)
5.37 ms ± 32.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank it is indeed faster ! Do you think we could get any improvement from this?

Comment: Probably. You'd have to say in detail what values are in population (are they always integers?) and what you want to use the resultant data for.

Comment: The population is always range(0,len(prob)). The result as dict is fine with me. I then call a function with arguments i,res[I].

Comment: But what is that function you call doing?