# Distribute values randomly over previous days

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks something like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":['2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-01-05','2021-01-06','2021-01-07'],'Value':[0,0,14,0,0,0,9]})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df

Date    Value
2021-01-01  0
2021-01-02  0
2021-01-03  14
2021-01-04  0
2021-01-05  0
2021-01-06  0
2021-01-07  9
```

I know that where the data is missing was due to a lack of reporting, so rows with values represents that day, plus the sum of values from the missing days as well. I want the outcome to randomly distribute the data backwards, based on the existing values, example below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":['2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-01-05','2021-01-06','2021-01-07'],'Value':[2,8,4,3,1,4,1]})
df2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2

Date    Value
2021-01-01  2
2021-01-02  8
2021-01-03  4
2021-01-04  3
2021-01-05  1
2021-01-06  4
2021-01-07  1
```

(The local 'totals' on 2021-01-03 and 2021-01-07 remain the same)

I know part of the problem is that the intervals of missing/present data isn't consistent...

Any ideas on how to get this done? All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a group up to a non zero Value with `ne` (not equal) to 0, `shift` to keep the non-zero value in the right group and `cumsum`.

Then to create a split per group of difference length summing to the non zero value of the group, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589214/generate-random-numbers-summing-to-a-predefined-value) for example.

so using [numpy.random.multinomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html) like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34998514/9274732)  you get:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

df['new_value'] = (
    df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(0).shift(1,fill_value=False).cumsum())
      ['Value'].apply(lambda x: np.random.multinomial(x.max(), [1./len(x)]*len(x)))
      .explode() # create a Series
      .to_numpy() # because index alignment not possible
)
print(df)
        Date  Value new_value
0 2021-01-01      0         4
1 2021-01-02      0         6
2 2021-01-03     14         4
3 2021-01-04      0         0
4 2021-01-05      0         2
5 2021-01-06      0         2
6 2021-01-07      9         5
```

or you can also use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3590105/9274732) that seems a bit more popular:

```
import random

def constrained_sum_sample_pos(n, total):
    """Return a randomly chosen list of n positive integers summing to total.
    Each such list is equally likely to occur."""

    dividers = sorted(random.sample(range(1, total), n - 1))
    return [a - b for a, b in zip(dividers + [total], [0] + dividers)]

df['new_value_r'] = (
    df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(0).shift(1,fill_value=False).cumsum())
      ['Value'].apply(lambda x: constrained_sum_sample_pos(len(x), x.max()))
      .explode()
      .to_numpy()
)
print(df)
        Date  Value new_value new_value_r
0 2021-01-01      0         4           5
1 2021-01-02      0         6           2
2 2021-01-03     14         4           7
3 2021-01-04      0         0           1
4 2021-01-05      0         2           2
5 2021-01-06      0         2           5
6 2021-01-07      9         5           1
```