# creating a function that takes into multiple dataframe columns and spilt value across the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sales dataframe with customer data and sales team. I have a target calls based on the individual customer which I want to split across the sales teams

```
 cust_id| total_calls_req| group_1_rep| group_2_rep| group_3_rep
 34523  |    10          | 230429     | nan        | 583985
 34583  |    12          | 230429     | 539409     | 583985
 34455  |    6           | 135552     | nan        | nan
```

I want to create a function that splits the `total_calls_req` across each group based on whether or not there is a group_rep assigned.

If `cust_id` is assigned to 1 rep then the `total_calls_req` is all assigned to the rep in question

If `cust_id` is assigned to 2 reps then the `total_calls_req` is split between the two reps in question.

If `cust_id` is assigned to 3 reps then the `total_calls_req` is split randomly between the three reps in question and needs to be whole cards.

I want the end dataframe to look like this:

```
 cust_id| total_calls_req| group_1_rep| group_2_rep| group_3_rep| group_1_rep_calls| group_2_rep_calls| group_3_rep_calls
 34523  |    10          | 230429     | nan        | 583985     |   5              | 0                |   5
 34583  |    12          | 230429     | 539409     | 583985     |   6              | 3                |   3
 34455  |    6           | 135552     | nan        | nan        |   6              | 0                |   0
```

Is there a way I can do that through a python function?

Comment: So the case with 3 reps and the random split means any combination of calls that add up to 12 (in the example)?  You show 6-3-3.  Could it be 10-1-1 or 0-4-8, etc?  And what if the 2-rep case has an odd number of calls?

Comment: @jch Yes it can be any random combination. If it is odd then you want split to either but it needs to be whole numbers adding up to the total

Comment: @dsexplorer any feedback on the answers? Has one of them solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a function which returns a serie with three elements according to the number of `NaN` values. I have based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34998514/4508767) to get the Series, in that answer is used [`numpy.random.multinomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html).

```
import numpy as np    

def serie_split(row):
  total_calls_req = row[0]
  groups = row[1:]
  numbers_nan = pd.notna(groups).sum()
  if numbers_nan == len(groups):
    s = pd.Series(np.random.multinomial(total_calls_req, [1/len(groups)] * len(groups)))
  else:
    s = pd.Series(groups)
    s.loc[s.notna()] = total_calls_req/numbers_nan if (total_calls_req % 2) == 0 else np.random.multinomial(total_calls_req, [1/numbers_nan] * numbers_nan)
    s.loc[s.isna()] = 0
  return s

def get_rep_calls(df):
  columns = df.filter(like='group_').add_suffix('_calls').columns
  dfg = df[df.columns[1:]] # dfg is a dataframe only with the columns 'total_calls_req','group_1_rep', 'group_2_rep' and 'group_3_rep'
  series = [serie_split(row) for row in dfg.to_numpy(dtype='object')]
  for index in range(len(dfg)):
    df.loc[index, columns] = series[index].values

get_rep_calls(df)
print(df)
```

**Output** *(I have added an example in the last row with `total_calls_req = 13`)*:

| cust_id | total_calls_req | group_1_rep | group_2_rep | group_3_rep | group_1_rep_calls | group_2_rep_calls | group_3_rep_calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34523 | 10 | 230429 | NaN | 583985 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 34583 | 12 | 230429 | 539409 | 583985 | 4 | 7 | 1 |
| 34455 | 6 | 135552 | NaN | NaN | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 12345 | 13 | 123456 | NaN | 583985 | 10 | 0 | 3 |

Comment: Thanks for this. How can i split odd values so i get whole numbers and still add to the total? Is there something i can add to this line `s.loc[s.isna()] = total_calls_req / numbers_nan`

Comment: You could do something with `np.random.multinomial`. Give me one second..

Comment: @dsexplorer I have updated my answer, please test again

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom `split` function to split the calls among reps that are assigned to the customer. This uses the columns starting in "group_" to identify the assigned reps and count how many they are. In case they are more than two, the [numpy.random.multinomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html) function enables to generate a random split.

```
import numpy as np

def split(s):
    reps = (~s.filter(like='group_').isna()).astype(int).add_suffix('_calls')
    total = reps.sum()
    if total > 2:   # remove this line and below for a better split across reps
        return np.random.multinomial(s['total_calls_req'], [1/total]*total)
    div, mod = divmod(int(s['total_calls_req']), total)
    reps = reps*div # split evenly
    reps[np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(reps), mod)]+=1 # allocate remainder randomly
    return reps

pd.concat([df, df.apply(split, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   cust_id  total_calls_req  group_1_rep  group_2_rep  group_3_rep  group_1_rep_calls  group_2_rep_calls  group_3_rep_calls
0    34523               10       230429          NaN     583985.0                  5                  0                  5
1    34583               12       230429     539409.0     583985.0                  4                  2                  6
2    34455                6       135552          NaN          NaN                  6                  0                  0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How can i split odd values so i get whole numbers. Also I changed the astype to string to help capture any nulls.

Comment: I updated the code for that. You could simplify it by removing the `if total > 2:` line and the one after. It would result in fair splits in all cases (even if reps > 2)