# Fairly distribute predefined value using binary array as mask

Tags: python, numpy

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68444495/creating-a-function-that-takes-into-multiple-dataframe-columns-and-spilt-value-a/68445306#68445306), I was wondering what is the most efficient/simple way to distribute a predefined value across the 1 values of a binary array. The value should be distributed as fairly as possible (the remainder is distributed randomly so that each cell can eventually get one extra).

For instance, distributing `4` in `[1, 0, 1]` would result in `[2, 0, 2]`, while distributing `5` could give either `[3, 0, 2]` or `[2, 0, 3]`. The distribution should work on an array of arbitrary dimensions.

Let's call `distribute` the function. It should take as parameters `value` the value to be distributed and `array` the binary array and return an array of same shape with the distributed value.

```
def distribute(value, array):
    ...
    return # array of same shape with fairly distributed value
```

```
>>> distribute(10, np.array([0,1]))
array([ 0, 10])

>>> distribute(10, np.array([1,0,1]))
array([5, 0, 5])

>>> distribute(9, np.array([1,0,1]))
array([4, 0, 5]) # could also be array([5, 0, 4])

>>> distribute(9, np.array([[1,0],[0,1]]))
array([[5, 0],
       [0, 4]])

>>> distribute(10, np.diag(np.ones(4)).reshape(2,2,-1))
array([[[3., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 3., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 2.]]])
```

See [my proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68453354/16343464) in the answers.  Please propose alternative approaches, the goal is to find the most efficient and/or simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def distribute(value, array):
    shape = array.shape # save the original shape of the array
    div, mod = map(int, divmod(value, np.sum(array))) # calculate equal split and remainder, ensuring int type
    array = (array*div).flatten() # distribute evenly and flatten
    array[np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(array), mod, replace=False)] += 1 # allocate remainder randomly
    return array.reshape(shape) # return the array reshaped as original
```

Comment: Add `replace = False` to the `np.random.choice` parameters to ensure the whole mod value is allocated.